# Incorrect DST start for Brazil in 2017

Tags: c#, c++, dst

In the 2017 DST starts in Brazil at 15th of October 00:00:00 (midnight) - [details](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/rio-de-janeiro?year=2017)

When I change to Brazil time zone in Windows and change the date to some days before 15th of October 2017 I see that the system correctly shows DST start date (there is an information displayed that DST will start on 15th of October).

The problem is that when I try to get DST start date from code it returns 22nd of October. I tried it both using c++ mktime and c# TimeZone.GetDaylightChanges.

Here is the c# code:

```
Console.WriteLine(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(2017).Start.ToString());
```

Result is:

```
10/21/2017 11:59:59 PM
```

Any idea why?

Comment: `TimeZone` is probably not appropriate to use. See the note to callers in `GetDaylightChanges`: Because the TimeZone class supports only one daylight saving time adjustment rule, the GetDaylightChanges method applies the current adjustment rule to any year, regardless of whether the adjustment rule actually applies to that year. What happens when you use `TimeZoneInfo`?

Comment: TimeZoneInfo works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TimeZone` class only supports one adjustment and can be wrong, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getdaylightchanges(v=vs.110).aspx.

It the **Note to callers** it recommends

> a more accurate result is available by working with the array of TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule objects returned by the TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules method. The Start, End, and Delta properties correspond to the TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.DateStart, TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.DateEnd, and TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.DaylightDelta properties.

Comment: Thank you, haven't notice this remark. Still strange that GetDaylightChanges is not taking into consideration dynamic DST settings from system (we can trust it then only in case we are sure that it will not be used in systems with dynamic DST changes). I assume that mktime works the same way.